# Fluid design using percentages for width, 1px border messes it up

Tags: html, css, percentage

Hopefully I provide enough information to combat the erroneous title.

I'm designing a website which has two main sections, a sidebar and a content section. The sidebar is on the left and content is on the right. So far I have this markup and CSS to go with it:

```
<section id="sidebar">
    sidebar
</section>
<section id="content">
    content
</section>

#sidebar {
    width: 29%;
    background: #f7f3ed;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 1%;
    text-align: right;
}

#content {
    width: 69%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    float: left;
}
```

Hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do here. I want the sidebar and content areas to be defined by percentages so when the browser window gets resized they stay in shape.

However, I want the sidebar to have a 1 pixel border on the right that separates it from the content area. When I add this, the content area gets pushed below the sidebar because the overall width is 1 pixel more than 100%.

Here's a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/juffd/

How can I apply the border without the content area wrapping under the sidebar and without specifically specifying the widths of each element in pixels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box;`. This makes the width of an element include its padding as well as any borders.

Comment: Never seen that property. Fixes it, thanks. Do you know what kind of browser support this has? I see it's a CSS3 element and with Mozilla/Webkit you need to use something like `-moz-box-sizing` so I'm guessing earlier versions of some browsers don't support it at all?

Comment: -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: Yeah, it's got pretty bad browser support. If you look up the vendor specific attributes it gets a little better.


If you don't want horizontal scroll bars to appear in older browsers you can add overflow-x: none; to the body and html attributes.